# Different treatment of ? in extends and super

Tags: java, generics

I expected that any type can be used instead of wildcard (?).

It is true with extends (as I expected), but it is a compile error with super (I don't understand why it is different from extends example).

How shall I think about this difference - is this a bug or a feature?

```
class Why {
    
    void fSuper(List<? super Map<String,?>> lst) {  }
    
    void fExtends(List<? extends Map<String,?>> lst) {  }

    void test(){
        
          // Why any type instead of ? gives error        
          fSuper(new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>()); // compile ERR - WHY ???
          fSuper(new ArrayList<Map<String, Byte>>());  // c. ERR - WHY ???
          fSuper(new ArrayList<Map<String, Map<Short, Boolean>>>()); // c. ERR - WHY ???         
          fSuper(new ArrayList<Map<String,?>>()); // OK
        
          // Any type instead of ? can be used OK   
          fExtends(new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>()); // OK
          fExtends(new ArrayList<Map<String, Byte>>());  // OK
          fExtends(new ArrayList<Map<String, Map<Short, Boolean>>>()); // OK     
          fExtends(new ArrayList<Map<String,?>>()); // OK
```

This question was inspired by example in answer of pdem [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22987844/what-is-wrong-with-my-method-generic-parameters)

His example seems very inconsistent with my IDE

```
void populateList(List<? super Map<String,?>> list) {
    list.clear();
    Map<String, String>  map;
    map = new HashMap<String,String>();
    map.put("key", "value"); // compiles
    // Map<String, String> for List<? super Map<String,?>>
    list.add(map);      // compiles !!
}
```

**P.S. I understand PECS (Producer extends / Consumer super).** (Please don't close the question for that reason).  But I don't see how to use it in my first code snippet. I think I fully understand the second code snippet. But I don't understand why `ArrayList<Map<String, String>>` does not compile in my first code snippet (with ...*? super*) and does compile in the second code snippet and does compile in my first code snippet (with ...? *extends*).

I also realize that using wildcards (?) is often a way to trouble (especially if violating PECS prescriptions).

But **I want to deeply understand generics, and the first code snippet beats my understanding so far.**

Comment: Is `Map<String, String>` a supertype or a subtype of `Map<String, ?>`? It can't be both. The only type that is both a supertype and a subtype of a type T is T itself. Every other type is one or the other (or neither).

Comment: Did you read here [Difference between <? super T> and <? extends T> in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4343202/difference-between-super-t-and-extends-t-in-java) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is PECS (Producer Extends Consumer Super)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2723397/what-is-pecs-producer-extends-consumer-super)

Comment: i suggest reading https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3546745/multiple-wildcards-on-a-generic-methods-makes-java-compiler-and-me-very-confu

Comment: did any of the answers help you?

Answer (score 0):

Based on the post suggested by @Nathan Hughes, I found [this excellent article](http://www.angelikalanger.com/GenericsFAQ/FAQSections/TechnicalDetails.html#FAQ206).

> A wildcard instantiation with a lower bound is supertype of all instantiations of the generic type where the type argument is a supertype of the lower bound.

In the current case, for `List<? super <Map<String, ?>>`, we can only assign types with type parameter that are super type of `Map<String, ?>`.

In general, for lower bound wildcard, we should be able to assign the type parameters in the reverse direction, (i.e., in a statement the type parameter in the LHS must be assignable to the type parameter in the RHS).

In the below code, we cannot assign the first 3 values to the type parameters. So neither can a subtype with this type parameter can be assigned to the list.

```
HashMap m = new HashMap();
Map<String, String> m1 = (Map<String, ?>)(m); //error
Map<String, Byte> m2 = (Map<String, ?>)(m); //error
Map<String, Map<Short, Boolean>> m3 = (Map<String, ?>)(m); //error
Map<String, ?> m4 = (Map<String, ?>)(m); // ok
```

Comment: or even [easier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847162/java-generics-super-keyword/64490493#64490493)

Answer (score 0):

This is not going to easy, nor short; but in essence it's not that complicated.

What you need to understand first is that *generics are invariant*, you can read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52224806/comparable-vs-extends-comparable/52225316#52225316) or a much longer read [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27902219/nested-wildcards/58631449#58631449) and the most recent answer I've made [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3847162/java-generics-super-keyword/64490493#64490493). In rather simple words:

```
Animal a = ...
Dog d = ...
a = d;
```

The assignment `a = d` works because `Dog` *is an* `Animal`; but at the same time:

```
List<Animal> a = new ArrayList<>();
List<Dog> d = new ArrayList<>();
a = d;
```

this will not work, because generics are *invariant* (the links above explain why this is so).

The easy part here is that a bounded type in the form of `? extends ...` is said to "make the type covariant", that is :

```
 List<? extends Animal> animals = new ArrayList<>();
 animals = d;
```

will work (as opposed to the example above `a = d`).

What if we want a List of List of Dogs? The naive approach says to try something like this:

```
 List<List<Dog>> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
 List<List<Animal>> animals = new ArrayList<>();
 animals = dogs;
```

which will fail, because we know already that `List<Animal>` can not be assigned to `List<Dog>` (in other words `List<Dog>` is not a *subtype* of `List<Animal>`). How about that `? extends...`?

```
 List<List<Dog>> dogs = new ArrayList<>();
 List<? extends List<Animal>> animals = new ArrayList<>();
 animals = dogs;
```

still no. To make the type assignable, you would need:

```
 List<? extends List<? extends Animal>> animals = new ArrayList<>();
 animals = dogs; // now it works
```

You can also make it work via:

```
 List<? extends List<?>> animals = new ArrayList<>();
```

because `?` is the super-type of all types.

---

We need this rather long intro because you are dealing with *nested* generics too. All the examples you have shown with `fExtends(...)` can be explained because:

- bounded types (`? extends...`) makes the type covariant (assignable)
- `Map<String, String>` or `Map<String, Byte>` or `Map<String, Map<Short, Boolean>>` or `Map<String, ?>` are *all* subtypes (or self) of : `Map<String,?>`.

For example all of these will compile:

```
 Map<String,?> one = new HashMap<>();
 Map<String, String> two = new HashMap<>();
 Map<String, Byte> three = new HashMap<>();
 // ... and so on for all the cases you have
 one = two;
 one = three;
```

---

The examples with `fSuper` are somehow more involved, but not really that complicated. Let's first look at the argument that it takes: `List<? super Map<String,?>>` : a list of an unknown type `X`, where `X` has to be a *supertype* (or self) of `Map<String,?>`. And this is why this :

```
fSuper(new ArrayList<Map<String, ?>>());
```

works: because you have passed a *self* type argument : `Map<String, ?>` (And `ArrayList` *is-a* `List`). I think this is rather easy for you to grasp.

This one:

```
fSuper(new ArrayList<Map<String, Map<Short, Boolean>>>())
```

does not compile because you need to pass a *supertype* of `Map<String,?>` and is this such a case? Let's illustrate:

```
method-argument:    Map < String,            ?          >
passed-value   :    Map < String,  Map<Short, Boolean>  >
```

Is `Map<Short, Boolean>` a *supertype* of `?`. No, it is a *subtype*, thus it fails.

In the same course:

- is `Byte` a *supertype* of `?`
- is `String` a *supertype* of `?`

that is why those methods fail, too.